# mount + mount: special device /dev/sdX does not exist

Tags: rhel, mount, ext4, fstab, block-device

we have rhel server version 7.5

and from lsblk we can see only the following disks , and all disks are with `ext4` filesystem

```
 lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0 278.9G  0 disk
├─sda1             8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2             8:2    0 278.4G  0 part
  ├─vgN-lv_root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vgN-lv_swap 253:1    0    16G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─vgN-lv_var  253:2    0   100G  0 lvm  /var
sdb                8:16   0   1.7T  0 disk /gr/sdb
sdc                8:32   0   1.7T  0 disk /gr/sdc
sdd                8:48   0   1.7T  0 disk /gr/sdd
sde                8:64   0   1.7T  0 disk /gr/sde
```

but the interesting thing is that:

when we performed `mount -a` we get

```
mount -a
mount: special device /dev/sdf does not exist
mount: special device /dev/sdg does not exist
```

we not understand from where `mount -a` gives this disks because they not appears from `lsblk` and also not from `/etc/fstab` and not also from  `/etc/mtab`

so why `mount -a` is complaint about this disks , how we can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your `/etc/fstab` specifies some mounts by either `UUID=` or `LABEL=` (causing `mount` to loop through all block devices it finds) and you have some garbage files as `/dev/sdf` and `/dev/sdg` that are not actual device nodes?

Run `ls -l /dev/sdf /dev/sdg`. If it displays anything, and the letter in the very first column of the permissions string is not `b`, those are not real block devices. They might have been created by an accidentally mistyped command or two earlier.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, just some suggestions...)

Could it be that on your system the mount command is wrapped in some script?

Could you please post the output of these...

```
mount --version
type mount
file -L $(which mount)
ls -la $(which -a mount)
cat /etc/fstab
```

Comment: mount --version
mount from util-linux 2.23.2 (libmount 2.23.0: selinux, debug, assert

Comment: file -L $(which mount)
/usr/bin/mount: setuid ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=8839ecc645f17975765632c4f5c6777e75258d01, stripped

Comment: ls -la $(which -a mount)
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 44224 Aug 21  2015 /usr/bin/mount

Comment: What about the last one?  cat /etc/fstab